# How to navigate to Different section in same page in Github Readme.md

Tags: github

I want to create a Table of Content in which I want to add links to navigate to different sections in the same readme page.
I am using this
`[Title of that Section](#id)`

but the prolem is that the id has spaces in between, used %20 to connect but not working in readme.md

```
## Table of Content 

* [Deployment](#deployment)
* [Tools and Technologies Used](#Tools%20and%20Technologies%20Used)
* [Usage](#usage)
* [Installation](#installation)
* [Contribution](#contribution)
* [License](#license)
```

[image]

What should I do to fix this.

Comment: It's Still not Working !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `%20` with `-` and do only use lowercase characters (it also works with uppercase, but lowercase should be preferred).

The link has to look like this:

```
[Tools and Technologies Used](#tools-and-technologies-used)
```

and will then match the title

```
### Tools and Technologies Used
```